# Pycharm hangs building skeleton for Kivy environment

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

I'm trying to setup a development environment for Kivy via PyCharm in Windows but the process seems to hang when it gets to the PIL._imagingtk package and doesn't progress.  I'm following the following guide on how to setup PyCharm to interpret Kivy:

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just hung for a good hour before continuing the process.

Comment: Ok...i'll give it an hour then :)